# I'm trying to convert from pure html code to Vuejs but it's not working

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

This is the logic algorithm I'm converting and it's not working.

`Popup.vue`

```
<script>
import '../../assets/style.css'
export default {
data(){
  return{
    ceos: [{name_ceo:"Mr. A",
            position_ceo:"CEO-GOSTREAM",
            content:"Lorem."},
            {name_ceo:"Mr. B",
            position_ceo:"CTO-GOSTREAM",
            content:"Lorem2."},
            {name_ceo:"Mr. C",
            position_ceo:"CGO-GOSTREAM",
            content:"Lorem3."},
        ]
  }
  
},

methods:{
  
  modalCeo(i){
    var modal = this.$refs.modal;
    modal[0].style.display="flex";
    ceos.forEach(element => {
        name_ceo1.innerHTML=ceos[i].name_ceo;
        position.innerHTML=ceos[i].position_ceo;
        content.innerHTML=ceos[i].content;
    });
    
},
closemodal(){
  var modal = this.$refs.modal;
    modal[0].style.display="none";
}

}
}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

My theme:

```
<template>
    <div class="ceo">
    <div ref="modal" class="ceo-popup">
      <div class="modal-content-ceo">
        <div class="btn-close-popup">
          <img src="../../assets/close.svg" id="btn-close-modal" type="button" @click="closemodal()">
        </div>
        <div class="content-main" v-for="(detail, index) in ceos" :key="index">
          <h3 id="name"></h3>
          <h5 id="position"></h5>
          <h6 id="intro-ceo"></h6>
        </div>
        <img class="buiding-popup" src="../../assets/Group 226.png" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="title">
      <h5>Đội ngũ GoStream</h5>
      <h2>Co-Founders</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="avatar-buiding">
      <img class="buiding" src="../../assets/building-0122.png" alt="">
      <div class="avatar ">
        <img src="../../assets/Profile1.png" @click="modalCeo(0)">

        <img src="../../assets//Profile2.png" alt="" @click="modalCeo(1)">

        <img src="../../assets/Profile3.png" alt="" @click="modalCeo(2)">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

I want when I click it, a pop up will appear showing the values ​​I have given.
Can you guys give me a solution to this problem?

```
<div class="avatar" v-for="(item, index) in images" :key="index" >
        <img :src="item.url" @click="modalCeo(index)">
      </div>
```

Script:

```
images:[
          {url: '../../assets/Profile1.png'},
          {url: '../../assets/Profile2.png'},
          {url: '../../assets/Profile3.png'},
        ]
```

Update on the code I worked on but it still can't render the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply achieve it by using Vue [Modal component](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/examples/modal.html).

Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    showModal: false,
    selectedCeo: [],
    ceos: [
      {name_ceo:"Mr. A",
       position_ceo:"CEO-GOSTREAM",
       content:"Lorem."},
      {name_ceo:"Mr. B",
       position_ceo:"CTO-GOSTREAM",
       content:"Lorem2."},
      {name_ceo:"Mr. C",
       position_ceo:"CGO-GOSTREAM",
       content:"Lorem3."}
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    modalCeo(index) {
        this.showModal = true;
        this.selectedCeo = this.ceos[index];
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.modal-vue .overlay {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9998;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}

.modal-vue .modal {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  z-index: 9999;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px 30px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.modal-vue .close{
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<!-- app -->
<div id="app" class="modal-vue">

  <!-- button show -->
  <button v-for="(item, index) in ceos" :key="index" @click="modalCeo(index)">{{ item.name_ceo }}</button>

  <!-- overlay -->
  <div class="overlay" v-if="showModal" @click="showModal = false"></div>

  <!-- modal -->
  <div class="modal" v-if="showModal">
    <button class="close" @click="showModal = false">x</button>
      <p>Name : {{ selectedCeo.name_ceo }}</p>
      <p>Position : {{ selectedCeo.position_ceo }}</p>
      <p>Content : {{ selectedCeo.content }}</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Note **:** I updated code snippet as per your comment. Instead of the profile pictures I used buttons just for the demo.

Comment: Thanks sir...
I edited the post and added my theme, could you take a look and give me some advice? Thank you very much.

Comment: @TungTran I saw your edited post and looks like you are fetching the details based on the user profile pic you clicked. In that case you can just filter out the data on click and then bind the selected user in the template.

Comment: @TungTran I updated code snippet as per your comment. Instead of the profile pictures I used buttons just for the demo. Hope it will help and please do accept the answer if it helps so that it will be useful for other developers as well.

Comment: Can you tell me more, instead of passing index what parameter i need to pass to my modalceo() for it to work?

Comment: @TungTran You can pass any property which is unique in all the objects. For example : you can also pass `name_ceo` and filtered out the list based on this parameter. Can you please accept this answer.

Comment: Can you help me give a suggestion, close button is working but show button still can't work, I have passed (i) into modalCeo... :( thanks sir

Comment: @TungTran `i` is basically a index and you should pass this if you are iterating your profile pics inside an `v-for` loop. Please have a look in my demo . You will understand the flow.

Comment: sorry to bother but i am new to Vue, one more question how can i put images or img tags in data() and v-for them to show? finally thank you so much

Comment: @TungTran No need to put whole `img` tag in data. You can just put the image src in the data as an array. for ex : `imageSrc: ['img1', 'img2', ...]` and then you can use `v-for` and bind these imageUrls in the image tag dynamically.

Comment: I updated a piece of code that I already have but still not working can you take a look at it help me? Thank you ^^

Comment: @TungTran Your code is looking fine. What issue you are getting ? Can you check the file path by inspect the element in the developer console.